# How to avoid image relocation sending an email using NSSharingService with HTML content

Tags: objective-c, macos, html-email

I am trying to send an email using NSSharingService from a Mac app. I am including HTML code as email body. When the Mail window appears, the content is formatted, but the image in the HTML structure is moved to the bottom email. Also, even though I define this image as a link, the link is not performed in the email body.

This is the code I am using:

```
NSString* htmlText = @"<html><body><p>Message body</p><br/><a href='http://www.google.com'><img border='0' src=http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg label='Video' width='512' height='512'></img></a><br/><p>Video: <a href='http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg'>http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg</a></p><br/><p>Another link to <a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>google</a></p></body></html>";

NSData* textData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[htmlText UTF8String] length:[htmlText lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSAttributedString* textAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:textData options:nil documentAttributes:nil];


NSSharingService *emailSharingService = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail];
[emailSharingService setSubject:@"Subject"];

emailSharingService.delegate = self;

NSArray* shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: textAttributedString, nil];

[emailSharingService performWithItems:shareItems];
```

The image should appear after "Message body" text line and before "Video:...", but in my case it appears in the bottom.

The HTML code is tested on Firefox and Safari. Also, I can open the HTML text with Safari, and selecting "File->Share->Send this page by email" it does exactly what I am trying to do (but using Safari, not with my app).

Any idea is wellcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the Apple Scripting bridge?

Comment: No, I never had. I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

I conducted a variety of tests using NSSharingService, including concatenating nsattributedstrings and using an NSTextAttachment, but it seems the NSSharingService (or NSAttributedString) always pushes the image to the end.

Try using the Apple Scripting bridge.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question but it seems no answer was found since it was asked and as of now (xCode 7 OSX 10.11), the problem is still present.

The solution I found is a bit of a hack but it keeps things simple and works (with mail.app) so I figured it could still help people in the future.

Instead of using an NSAttributed string, I encoded the variable containing the HTML text in a fake URL.  This makes mail.app treat it as an attachment and I found that it shows its content in an html `<a>` tag as if it were an internal hyperlink.

Here's the code I used (in Swift):

```
 var eMailService:NSSharingService! = NSSharingService(named:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)

 eMailService.subject = mySubject

 let message         = "<html><body>Message body ...</body></html>"     
 let embeddedMessage = "</a>" + message 
 if let encodedMessage  = embeddedMessage.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters
                                        (NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()),
    let urlMessage = NSURL(string:encodedMessage)!
 { 
   eMailService.performWithItems([urlMessage])
 }
```

Note1: the "/a" tag i'm inserting at the beginning of my embedded message is there to prevent the whole html content to be highlighted as an hyperlink (because mail.app places my URL inside an "a" tag, I just close it there).

Note2: this causes NSSharingService to complain about the URL not being absolute (in the log) but it still inserts it properly in the email.  I could silence this error by adding "data:" ahead of my inserted "/a" tag but then "data:" appears on the eMail (which I didn't like).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Alain. It works perfectly on mail.app. However, do you know how to make it work for Outlook as well because for Outlook the format becomes very bad and just looks like gibberish!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with any other mail clients.  You may want to look at the raw content of the messages (as received by the mail client) to see if there are other possible "hacks" with the html tags. That's how I came to this "solution".

Comment: I tried that but Outlook just messes up the HTML completely. Thanks!

Comment: Wow genius!. @RajeevBhatia, Use SBApplication to compose the outlook email and make sure to set composeMessagesInHtmlByDefault = YES.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but, here is something I have just figured out (after seeing Apple's own code do this, and swizzling several methods on many public & private classes to see how it works):

The following code will share html & render as expected in the Apple's Mail.app's composer (not sure about other email clients):-

```
NSString *htmlText = @"<html><body><p>Message body</p><br/><a href='http://www.google.com'><img border='0' src=http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg label='Video' width='512' height='512'></img></a><br/><p>Video: <a href='http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg'>http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg</a></p><br/><p>Another link to <a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>google</a></p></body></html>";

NSAttributedString* textAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:htmlText];

NSSharingService *emailSharingService = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail];
[emailSharingService setSubject:@"Subject"];

emailSharingService.delegate = self;

NSArray* shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: textAttributedString, nil];

[emailSharingService performWithItems:shareItems];
```

Note how I create & share the `NSAttributedString` in the above code sample.

The only caveat I have discovered is that the string needs to have correct opening & closing `html` & `body` tags. It does not render correctly if these tags aren't present in your string.

I have tested this on macOS Monterey, but, I think it works on Big Sur as well. I'm not so sure about older versions of macOS though.

And, finally, this, as far as I'm aware, is **undocumented behaviour**, so, use with caution.